# A modern reference for the "Intermediate Derivatives Theorem"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces, interpolation-spaces

In the book *Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications I* by Lions and Magenes, the Intermediate Derivative Theorem is stated as follows:

> **Intermediate Derivative Theorem:** Let $X\subset Y$ be a dense continuous injection of separable (complex) Hilbert spaces. Define $$W^m(a,b,X,Y)=\{u\in L^2(a,b;X)\ |\ \partial_t^m u\in L^2(a,b;Y)\}$$ where we define $\mathcal{D}'((a,b);X)=\mathscr{L}(C_c^\infty((a,b)),X)$, with the norm on $W^m$ given by  $$\lVert u\rVert_{W^m(a,b,X,Y)}^2=\lVert u\rVert_{L^2(a,b;X)}^2+\lVert u\rVert_{L^2(a,b;Y)}^2 .$$ Let $u\in L^2(a,b;X)$, and $\partial_t^m u\in L^2(a,b;Y)$ distributionally. Then $$\partial_t^j u\in L^2(a,b;[X,Y]_{j/m})$$ for all $0\le j\le m$, and $$\partial_t^j:W^m(a,b,X,Y)\to L^2(a,b;[X,Y]_{j/m})$$ is continuous for all $0\le j\le m$.

In the book, $[X,Y]_{j/m}$ is defined using domains of unbounded operators, but I believe in this case that complex interpolation is equivalent.

However, the proof as given in the book is incredibly long and unwieldily, using many techniques such as measurable Hilbertian sums, and interpolation via domains of operators, and I suspect that a better proof should exist using complex interpolation. However, I have been unable to find a reference for any "Intermediate Derivative Theorem" in the literature, which suggests that this result may go by another name?

Any modern reference for this theorem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no one would call it "modern" but maybe you want to take a look in Triebel's book (Ch. 1.8, in particular 1.8.3) if you haven't already. You will see that the theory concerns real interpolation spaces there, which I would consider more natural here due to the definition of the trace method for real interpolation.